Confusion about mock reuse in phpunit
i'm writing some unit tests and became stuck at what i first thought was a bug, but after much frustration seems to be intended (but impossible to find documentation/mention of) behaviour/usage.
The minimum example case looks like this:
class UpdateListener() 
{
  public function handleStatusChange(UpdateUpdated $event): void
  {
    //checks various conditions of $event and modifies $successful_update_at
  }
}

class CandidateTest extends TestCase
{
  public function testSuccessfulUpdateTimestampManagement(): void
  {
    $updateListener = new UpdateListener();

    //The first test verifies that a new timestamp is set 
    //when creating a mock with second argument set "true"
    $updateEvent = $this->mockUpdateEvent(UpdateEvent::class, true);
    $updateListener->handleStatusChange($updateEvent);
    $this->assertEquals('2024-05-19', $candidate->successful_update_at->format('Y-m-d'));

    //The second test sets "false" on the second argument and expects null on the attribute
    $updateEvent = $this->mockUpdateEvent(UpdateEvent::class, false);
    $updateListener->handleStatusChange($updateEvent);
    $this->assertNull($candidate->successful_update_at);
  }

  private function mockUpdateEvent(string $class, bool $findsPreviousUpdate): UpdateEvent
  {
    $mockUpdate = \Mockery::mock(Update::class);
    $mockUpdate->makePartial();

    $previousSuccessfulUpdate = new Update();
    $previousSuccessfulUpdate->register_date = '2024-05-19';

    $mockQueryBuilder = \Mockery::mock(Builder::class);

    //This is where the magic is supposed to happen, but seems completely ignored
    $mockQueryBuilder->shouldReceive('getResult')->andReturn(
      $findsPreviousUpdate ? $previousSuccessfulUpdate : null
    );

    $mockUpdate->shouldReceive('query')->andReturn($mockQueryBuilder);

    return new $class($mockUpdate);
  }
}

So what's going on in this minimum example is that i'm (or i thought i was) creating clean mocks of a class that uses a query builder (laravel 11 if it has any importance) to "find" an object under certain conditions, and use the timestamp of that object on the mock subject. Under some conditions, i'm expecting null return, and i'm using that second argument flag to tell the mock what it should be returning.
However, this is where we get to the "Problem": the second assertion is never null, the mock is always returning the $previousSuccessfulUpdate regardless of what i'm telling it to return when creating the mock.
So after looking both at what mockery::mock and ->andReturn does, it's clear that theres some sort of reuse of mock objects and return expectations going on under the hood.
What would be the proper way to run this sort of assertion on the same mocked object while expecting different results from mocked methods? Am i missing something basic that would make this work as i expect? Splitting assertions into different tests to get some sort of tearDown to reset my mocks?
As ->andReturn seems to use a "queue" of returned responses, i'm getting the expected assertions by simply giving it the different expected return values in the order i expect them. This feels like a very "hard coded" way of doing it, and implies i must know the exact order and amount of returns that i expect any test to be giving for any mock. I would much rather be able to specify at any point in time exactly what the mock should be returning, altering it whenever i see fit...? Also, it feels super wrong to not be creating multiple mocks but effectively assigning all the expected return data on "every" mock.
$mockQueryBuilder->shouldReceive('getResult')->andReturn($previousSuccessfulUpdate, null);

Phpunit: 11.1.2,
Mockery: 1.6.11

Hej, this is interesting what you are experiencing, I were trying to get my mocks running all the afternoon, having a similar issue. Though in my case, the number of times a method should be called gets cached somehow and the assertions are not correct in the end even though when debugging into my class under test, the expectations stored with the mocked object are. I'm running phpunit@11.1.3 and mockery@1.6.11, which versions are you running?

Interesting, i added versions at end of post, seems to be pretty much same

Perhaps an alternative viewpoint: Don't mock, have a test-database you can run the dirty stuff against and use the tests to break it. Laravel makes it easy to have a test-database and it does not even endanger the "live" database you have for the application under development right next to it. Mocking the query builder? Mocking on it's own sounds cumbersome and then mocking the query builder even more (in my ears). Write more high level methods you can can easily mock if you really want to mock, design for testing, not mock creations. Just my 2 cents.
